# Refresh Facebook API Graph token

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm trying to exchange a fb API Graph token with a long-lived one according to the explanation given in this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#long-via-code)

Here what I do

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={"+app_id+"}&client_secret={"+secret+"}&fb_exchange_token={"+old_token+"}"

resp = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
print resp
```

Here the result

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid Client ID","type":"OAuthException","code":101,"fbtrace_id":"Bjvz2LDzJhs"}}
```

I'm using Python, I know that there is not an official SDK but I just need to crawl some post and save related data.
I don't understand what is happening, why does the client id should be not valid?
PS: the old_token works

thanks in advance!

Comment: `{}` do not belong into the URL, they are just meant to show that these are placeholders ...

Comment: ok thanks, but it is still not working. After I applied your suggestion, the response message said that the token doesn't belong to the app. Therefore I generated the app token at this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/) which gave me an user token and an app token. Then I used the app token in lieu of the "old_token" but I get another error saying  "No user access token specified"